# can't bind Formik Validations Errors for an array of object

Tags: reactjs, typescript, formik, yup

I have a form that contains two fields: boolean value and array of objects.
when the boolean value is true then the array should be required.
and the array have two string fields one is required and the other is not.

**Validation Schecma**

```
  const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    boolVal: Yup.boolean().required().nullable(),
    arr: Yup.array().when('boolVal', {
      is: true,
      then: Yup.array(
        Yup.object().shape({
          str1: Yup.string().nullable(),
          str2: Yup.string().required()
          ),
        })
      ),
    }),
  })
```

**initialValues**

```
const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: 
                  {
                    boolVal:false,
                    arr: [new MyObject()]
                  }
})
```

when i try to render the error for a specific element of the array like this

```
formik.errors.arr[0]
```

i got this error

> Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {str2}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

and when i hover over the 'arr' to see the type of it, it gives me

> (property) arr?: string | string[] | FormikErrors < MyObject > []

when i render the errors using this line of code

```
{JSON.stringify(formik.errors.arr)}
```

it shows me

> { "arr" : [ { "str2": "str2 is required" } ] }

Answer (score 2):

I was facing a similar issue but I solved it using `getIn`.

You can use it by following:

```
import { getIn } from 'formik';

getIn(formik.errors, 'arr[0]');
```

[image]

To refer formik documentation:https://formik.org/docs/api/fieldarray#fieldarray-validation-gotchas